# Collect And Validate Parameters Out of Order

Tags: f#

I have input that is provided in a list without any guaranteed order.  I need to take that input, validate it, and return either the object or an error message.

I thought about using a recursive accumulator to grab the parameters, but I can't figure out how to process the result.  Is there a better way of doing this?  This would be easy with mutable values.

```
let bind x f =
    f x
        
type Customer =
    {
    firstName : string
    lastName : string
    email : string
    }
    static member create fname lname email =
        {firstName = fname; lastName = lname; email = email}

let input = [ "email:bad email@won't work"; "firstName:Fred"; "lastName:" ]

let createCustomer input : Result<Customer, string> =
    let rec build firstNameAcc lastNameAcc emailAcc xs =
        match xs with
        | x::xs ->
            match x with
            | Prefix "firstName:" x -> build (validateName x) lastNameAcc emailAcc xs
            | Prefix "lastName:" x -> build firstNameAcc (validateName x) emailAcc xs
            | Prefix "email:" x -> build firstNameAcc lastNameAcc (validateEmail x) xs
            | _ -> Error "invalid argument"
        | _ ->  // how do you chain the results together?
            let retCustomer =
                Customer.create
                |> bind "firstname"
                |> bind "last"
                |> bind "email"
                
            Ok retCustomer
           
    let x = Error "Value Missing"
    build x x x input
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `List.fold` to accumulate a triple of options of `fname`, `lname`, and `email`. After that, the resulted triple is checked and if all three values are presented, the final customer is created.

The code would be:

```
let createCustomer input =
    let triple =
        input
        |> List.fold
            (fun triple param ->
                match triple with
                | Error _ -> triple
                | Ok (fname, lname, email) ->
                    match param with
                    | Prefix "firstName:" x when validName x -> Ok (Some x, lname, email)
                    | Prefix "lastName:" x when validName x -> Ok (fname, Some x, email)
                    | Prefix "email:" x when validEmail x -> Ok (fname, lname, Some x)
                    | _ -> Error "invalid argument")
            (Ok (None, None, None))
    match triple with
    | Error x ->
        Error x
    | Ok (Some fname, Some lname, Some email) ->
        Ok (Customer.create fname lname email)
    | _ ->
        Error "missing argument"
```

Or we can save several lines of code with `Result.bind` and function composition:

```
let createCustomer =
    List.fold
        (fun triple param ->
            triple |> Result.bind (fun (fname, lname, email) ->
                match param with
                | Prefix "firstName:" x when validName x -> Ok (Some x, lname, email)
                | Prefix "lastName:" x when validName x -> Ok (fname, Some x, email)
                | Prefix "email:" x when validEmail x -> Ok (fname, lname, Some x)
                | _ -> Error "invalid argument"))
        <| Ok (None, None, None)
    >> Result.bind (function
        | Some fname, Some lname, Some email -> Ok <| Customer.create fname lname email
        | _ -> Error "missing argument")
```

Comment: Or (to continue the refactoring), change the signature of create function to `string -> string -> string -> Result<Customer, string>` and do the validation there.

Comment: Thank you.  I don't know why I tend to use tail rec over List.fold.  This is great, except I can't grab an error msg off of the validate functions, but using Option to put them in order will let me do a separate Result pipeline like Guran said for validation.

Comment: Yep. And you should mark the structure of Customer as private to prevent outside to create invalid values of Customer. Every creation must go through the Customer.create method.

Comment: Is there a pattern for working with input where you have a validated type like Customer and a pre-validated type where all of the fields are options?  The next issue I'm facing is not wanting to throw away validated input while waiting for the user to refine invalid or missing input.

Comment: We can borrow the idea from [Java Builder Pattern](https://www.journaldev.com/1425/builder-design-pattern-in-java) in which we create a new type called `CustomerBuilder` to hold pre-validated fields. To my knowledge, I don't know an official similar pattern in FP/F# world.